# Rails : Checked checkboxes in form submit confirmation message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, view, submit

I want to provide a confirmation message that lists the checked checkboxes in the message.

Right now I have this:

`= submit_tag "Delete history and/or queues", :class => "button btn", :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete these?"`

Instead of "delete these" I would like to specifically list the items checked. Is there a straight-forward way to do this without Javascript, or, since these are events, I have to use Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you have to use JS (the confirmation is also a JS function provided by Rails).
You should give more info (and code) if you need more help about the JS implementation.

Comment: The JS implementation is pretty straight-forward, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some handy way to get the info I needed from the form code submission itself. I was really wondering if the params hash could be available for the view to use *after* the submit button is clicked but *before* the form is actually submitted. It seems like it should be. And if it were, I could pull out what I needed from that hash instead of using jQuery to capture the checkboxes.

Comment: if you want to send params, you would be doing some ajax. It could be done by using `:data_remote => true` in the form tag and rendering a file.js.erb with the alert and message from your controller. That would be harder, and less maintainable than doing some jquery.